# Nested dictionary without hard-coding

Tags: python-3.x

The following is my dictionary :

```
'relay': ['S1=OFF,S2=OFF,S3=OFF,S4=OFF'],
```

I want an o/p as such:(like a nested dictionary)

```
'relay': [['S1':'OFF'],['S2':'OFF'],['S3','OFF'],['S4':'OFF']]
```

The problem is that I cannot hard-code the keys and values, it might change during run time.Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you want the value to be a list of lists? Or a list of dictionaries? Because the current dictionary is *not* syntactically valid.

Comment: In your desired output. It is niether a `list` nor a `dict`

Comment: i want the o/p as dictionaries

Comment: @geetha: like this (see edit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way could be this:

> *However I am making the assumption that:*
>
> Values that are `dictified` (by lack of a better name) are always in the form of `['abc=def,abc=...']`

```
d =  {'panel': ['STDSWB'], 'relay': ['S1=OFF,S2=OFF,S3=OFF,S4=OFF']}

from collections import defaultdict

def dictionary_maker(d, key):

    # Makes new dict to add to previous dictionary
    new_dict = defaultdict(dict)

    # foreach value in the list
    for v in d[key]:
        for i in v.split(','):
            d_new = i.split('=')
            # populate new dict
            new_dict[key][d_new[0]] = d_new[1]

    # remove old key and add new key
    d.pop(key, None)
    d[key] = dict(new_dict[key])
    return d
            
d = dictionary_maker(d, 'relay')
print (d)
# d = {'panel': ['STDSWB'], 'relay': {'S1': 'OFF', 'S2': 'OFF', 'S3': 'OFF', 'S4': 'OFF'}}
```

Now you can look at the values of 'S2' for instance by doing something like:

```
print (d['relay']['S2']) #OFF
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the same but without hard-coding relay.

Comment: *Edit* and made a function for it so maybe you can use it for multiple keys. Hope this helps

Comment: But in this line we are hard coding relay into the dic right.So this wil not work if i want to perform the same with some other dictionary.                            d = dictionary_maker(d, 'relay')

Comment: Just iterate over the keys and see if it needs to be dictified then add do the `dictionary_maker` function with that key. But to be honest, if there is even a need for something like this. Your code is probably wrong somewhere else. This was more an example then how it should be done

Answer (score 2):

Given the string is a *comma separated list of key/values* where the keys and the values are separated by the equal sign, you can use *nested dictionary comprehension*:

```
d['relay'] = dict(v.split('=',1) for v in d['relay'][0].split(','))
```

This produces:

```
>>> d =  {'panel': ['STDSWB'], 'relay': ['S1=OFF,S2=OFF,S3=OFF,S4=OFF']}
>>> d['relay'] = dict(v.split('=',1) for v in d['relay'][0].split(','))
>>> d
{'relay': {'S2': 'OFF', 'S4': 'OFF', 'S1': 'OFF', 'S3': 'OFF'}, 'panel': ['STDSWB']}
```

Comment: @geetha: `d` should be the original dictionary. You can replace it with the name of your variable.

Comment: @geetha: can you post your original dictionary (or a minimal version) with the error.

Comment: The following is my original dic                                                            {'panel': ['STDSWB'],
 'relay': ['S1=OFF,S2=OFF,S3=OFF,S4=OFF']}. I want to make a nested dic

Comment: @geetha: but here your `'STDSWB'` has no value. Then what should the output look like?

Comment: @geetha: updated. Please next time, try to make the question more clear.

Comment: @geetha: you should inspect `d` fully. If it is still not what you want, edit your **question** and provide clear input and output.

Comment: this is my dic d=  'sensor': ['temp=00',
                                            'light=0 0',
                                            'pir=0 0',
                                            'audio=0 0',
                                            'occupancy=0 0',
                                            'current=0 0'],
                                  'switch': ['S1=OFF,S2=OFF,S3=OFF,S4=OFF']}
expected o/p:'sensor': {'temp': ['00'],'light':'0 0,'pir':'0 0....and so on'},
                      'switch': {'S1': ['OFF'], 'S2': ['OFF'], 'S3': ['OFF'], 'S4':  ['OFF']}}